# How To Loop Through An Array Object Of Unknown Properties In Angular

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angular

so I was finding it difficult phrasing the title of my question, what i want to do is loop through and array of objects but i dont know the property's of the object because its dynamic and coming from a db.

Below is an example of the array object:

```
[{
    "id": 9,
    "event_id": 13,
    "details": {
        "firstname": "Ralph",
        "lastname": "Marvin",
        "email_address": "ralphmarvin@email.com",
        "phone_number": "0987654321"
    }
}, {
    "id": 10,
    "event_id": 13,
    "details": {
        "firstname": "John",
        "lastname": "X Doe",
        "email_address": "john_x_doe120@xmail.com",
        "phone_number": "0009876543"
    }
}, {
    "id": 11,
    "event_id": 13,
    "details": {
        "firstname": "Wari",
        "lastname": "Gumah",
        "email_address": "gumahwarihanna@eeee.com",
        "phone_number": "120029182765"
    }
}]
```

I want to display the details part of the object in a table that looks like this:

```
firstname     lastname      email_address       phone_number
```

and the values appropriately under each value.
An using Angular 8.

I just dont know how to use *ngFor to access properties i dont even know.
Is what am trying to do even possible, if yes then please show me how.

Thanks!.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over object key/values as inner for loop with  `keyvalue pipe` accessing details object.

Html:

```
  <table>
     <tr>              
       <th>Firstname</th>
       <th>lastname</th>
       <th>email_address</th>
       <th>phone_number</th>
     </tr>
     <tr *ngFor="let listItem of yourList" >
       <td *ngFor="let innerItem of listItem.details | keyvalue"> 
         {{innerItem.value}
       </td>
     </tr>
   </table>
```

populated list

```
   yourList = [{
    "id": 9,
    "event_id": 13,
    "details": {
      "firstname": "Ralph",
      "lastname": "Marvin",
      "email_address": "ralphmarvin@email.com",
      "phone_number": "0987654321"
    }
    }, {
    "id": 10,
    "event_id": 13,
    "details": {
      "firstname": "John",
      "lastname": "X Doe",
      "email_address": "john_x_doe120@xmail.com",
      "phone_number": "0009876543"
   }
   }, {
   "id": 11,
   "event_id": 13,
   "details": {
     "firstname": "Wari",
     "lastname": "Gumah",
     "email_address": "gumahwarihanna@eeee.com",
     "phone_number": "120029182765"
    }
   }]
```

Answer (score -1):

you could implement some logic on a component to get a set of fields. it Would look in some way like this: (I assume that items come as @Input() to your component, but it could be another source)

```
@Input() items: Item[];
fields: Set<string>;
ngOnChanges(changes) {
  if(!changes.items || !this.items) return;
  this.fields= new Set(this.items.flatMap(item => Object.keys(item.details)))
}
```

and then in the template

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of items">
   <td *ngFor="let field of fields">{{item.details[field]}}</td>
</tr>
```